# Compile only some C files in src folder

Tags: r, makefile

Is there a way to compile only some *.c (or *.cpp) files in src folder and not all of them? Perhaps it may be possible by modifying Makevars somehow?

A bit of background: I made a mistake of committing some files to the git master branch and would be easier for me to avoid their compilation rather than renaming them all or removing the branch.

Comment: "Would be easier for me to avoid their compilation rather than renaming them all or removing the branch."  I can see how it would be easier but I can't imagine it would be more sensible!

Comment: Perhaps just specify them in the `.Rbuildignore` file?

Comment: .Rbuildignore will work when distributing a source package, but when you are building locally with devtools, pkgbuild, etc., this file doesn't seem to be referenced, and everything in src is built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really is a Makefile (language) question that you can address via a `Makevars` file with proper settings.

But beware:

1. R *really* prefers the default settings and its implicit Makefile. You can get by with Makevars for settings things like compiler / linker options, doing dependencies among files *right* is much harder. Very few packages do it right. You are more likely to break dual-architecture builds on, eg, OS X and (via Makevars.win) on Windows.
2. There is no reason to leave the repo in a sad state. Just clean up your git repo, and the world will be a better place too.

Comment: So the answer is: don't do it. I removed the offending files, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is the best way to go.